# Getting error while installing Wine

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dependencies

I want to use LTspice on  my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
But it is not available for Ubuntu, so my Professor suggested me to download Wine.

I did all the steps as mentioned in https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.

However in the last step, when I type `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

I am getting this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.2~focal)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1.Enable 32-bit architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

2.Download and install the repository key

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key; sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

3.Add wine repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

NOTE: Replace `focal` with `eoan` for Ubuntu 19.10,
`bionic` for Ubuntu 18.04,
`xenial` for Ubuntu 16.04

4.Add PPA for the required `libfaudio0` library

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

5.Do an update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

6.Install Wine 5.0 stable

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: i did as you mentioned, but it didn't worked, it shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the community, i got the answer.

You can check here [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some packages has to be downgraded, if you run down through dependencies, you will see something like 'libxxx (ver 20.04ubuntu9) installed, but (ver. 20.04) needed'.
To resolve it on 20.04LTS focal put/create in file `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=focal
Pin-Priority: 1001`
```

execute:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install wine-stable
```

optionally clean `/etc/apt/preferences` and `apt update; apt upgrade`